# Joining two subqueries in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, subquery, average

Trying to run an inner join on two subqueries but I receive the error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "JOIN"
  Position: 550
  GROUP BY year 
JOIN temp ON temp.year = MN.ye
^
  -- INNER JOIN (
```

Here is a my query

```
   WITH temp as(
      SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN rain = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END)*1.0/COUNT(date) * 100 as rain, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
        FROM sample
      GROUP BY year
      )
    SELECT AVG(mind) as avg_min,
        AVG(maxd) as avg_max,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year
      FROM sample MN
      GROUP BY year 
    JOIN temp ON temp.year = MN.year
```

and a sample of my data

```
date    prcp    maxd    mind    rain
1948-01-01 00:00:00 0.47    51  42  TRUE
1948-01-02 00:00:00 0.59    45  36  TRUE
1948-01-03 00:00:00 0.42    45  35  TRUE
1948-01-04 00:00:00 0.31    45  34  TRUE
1948-01-05 00:00:00 0.17    45  32  TRUE
1948-01-06 00:00:00 0.44    48  39  TRUE
1948-01-07 00:00:00 0.41    50  40  TRUE
1948-01-08 00:00:00 0.04    48  35  TRUE
1948-01-09 00:00:00 0.12    50  31  TRUE
1948-01-10 00:00:00 0.74    43  34  TRUE
1948-01-11 00:00:00 0.01    42  32  TRUE
1948-01-12 00:00:00 0   41  26  FALSE
1948-01-13 00:00:00 0   45  29  FALSE
1948-01-14 00:00:00 0   38  26  FALSE
1948-01-15 00:00:00 0   34  31  FALSE
1948-01-16 00:00:00 0   34  28  FALSE
1948-01-17 00:00:00 0   35  29  FALSE
1948-01-18 00:00:00 0   33  28  FALSE
1948-01-19 00:00:00 0   34  27  FALSE
1948-01-20 00:00:00 0   36  29  FALSE
1948-01-21 00:00:00 0   48  32  FALSE
1948-01-22 00:00:00 0.21    47  44  TRUE
1948-01-23 00:00:00 0   47  43  FALSE
1948-01-24 00:00:00 0.1 45  34  TRUE
1948-01-25 00:00:00 0   46  30  FALSE
1948-01-26 00:00:00 0   45  32  FALSE
1948-01-27 00:00:00 0   53  33  FALSE
1948-01-28 00:00:00 0   53  25  FALSE
1948-01-29 00:00:00 0.22    42  34  TRUE
1948-01-30 00:00:00 0.03    47  30  TRUE
1948-01-31 00:00:00 0.21    35  27  TRUE
```

My ideal result would be something resembling this

```
avg_tmin, avg_tmax, avg_rain, year
 x          x         x       1948
 x          x         x       1949
...
```

So the average mind(tmin), maxd(tmax) and rain for each year in my dataset

Comment: GROUP BY comes after JOIN.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: @jarlh since i'm trying to find the average in the second subquery if I run groupby after join then I cannot carry out the aggregation in the second subquery and get the error message that column mn.year does not exist

Comment: @GMB I have added my desired result

Comment: I can't see any _second subquery_.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the logic your query tries to implement. From your sample data and expected results, however, it looks like you just want aggregation:

```
select
    avg(mind) avg_mind,
    avg(maxd) avg_maxd,
    avg( (rain)::int ) avg_rain,
    extract(year from date) year
from sample
group by extract(year from date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a JOIN to begin with:

```
SELECT count(*) filter (where rain = 'TRUE') * 1.0  / count(*) as rain, 
       AVG(mind) as avg_min,
       AVG(maxd) as avg_max,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
FROM sample
GROUP BY year
```

---

The above is the most efficient way to do what you want.

However, to answer your direct question why your code doesn't work: you need to move the group by after the join and you can't use the column alias `year` on the same level (`mn`) where you defined it:

```
WITH temp as (
  SELECT count(*) filter (where rain = 'TRUE') *1.0 / COUNT(date) * 100 as rain, 
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
  FROM sample
  GROUP BY year
), 
SELECT AVG(mn.mind) as avg_min,
       AVG(mn.maxd) as avg_max,
       tmp.year 
FROM sample MN
  JOIN temp ON temp.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mn.date)
GROUP BY tmp.year
```

Note that this does not use the `rain` column from the CTE. If you want to add that, you either need to include it in the group by:

```
WITH temp as (
  SELECT count(*) filter (where rain = 'TRUE') *1.0 / COUNT(date) * 100 as rain, 
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
  FROM sample
  GROUP BY year
), 
SELECT AVG(mn.mind) as avg_min,
       AVG(mn.maxd) as avg_max,
       tmp.year, 
       tmp.rain
FROM sample MN
  JOIN temp ON temp.year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mn.date)
GROUP BY tmp.year, tmp.rain
```

Or split this up in two aggregation queries that are joined.

```
WITH temp1 as (
  SELECT count(*) filter (where rain = 'TRUE') *1.0 / COUNT(date) * 100 as rain, 
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
  FROM sample
  GROUP BY year
), temp2 as (
  SELECT AVG(mind) as avg_min,
         AVG(maxd) as avg_max,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) as year 
  FROM sample MN
  GROUP BY year 
)
select *
from temp1
  join temp2 using (year);
```

But again: the join is not needed and makes the whole thing less efficient.